# ArrayList trouble to pick double variable 'Method call expected'

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, double

Learning java, and it's typical practice to make bank account classes,

but I have one problem.

in my 'Person' class,

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private String personId;
    private String e_mail;
    private ArrayList accountsOwned;

    public Person(String personId) {
        this.accountsOwned = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        this.personId = personId;
    }
    ...

    public double totalBalanceOfAccountsOwned(){
        double totalBalance = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < accountsOwned.size(); i++){
            totalBalance += accountsOwned((i)).getBalance();
            //getBalance() is method in BankAccount class
        }
        return totalBalance;
    }
}
```

in my main(test) class,

```
    ba1_1 = new BankAccount("act001", 100);
    ba1_2 = new BankAccount("act001", 200);
    ba1_3 = new BankAccount("act001", 300);
    ba2_1 = new BankAccount("act001", 400);
    ba2_2 = new BankAccount("act001", 500);//(String, double)

    ba1_1.setOwner(p1);
    ba1_2.setOwner(p1);
    ba1_3.setOwner(p1);

    p1.getAccountsOwned().add(ba1_1);
    p1.getAccountsOwned().add(ba1_2);
    p1.getAccountsOwned().add(ba1_3);

    p2.getAccountsOwned().add(ba2_1);
    p2.getAccountsOwned().add(ba2_2);
    p2.getAccountsOwned().add(ba1_3);
```

Problem is method 'totalBalanceOfAccountsOwned' in Person class,

accountsOwned((i)).getBalance(); part in for loop makes compile error

'Method call expected'.

I'm totally new at ArrayList, so I can't figure out what is problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change

```
private ArrayList accountsOwned;
```

to

```
private ArrayList<BankAccount> accountsOwned;
```

as when you are getting the bank account later, java doesn't know its a bank account and only thinks its a Object

Then as Kon said above, use

```
accountsOwned.get(i).getBalance();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't dereference a `List` object or its implementing classes using `array` syntax. For example,

```
list(0)
```

and

```
list[0]
```

are invalid. Instead you want

```
list.get(0);
```